# Windows terminal, start two commands in tabs

Tags: windows-terminal

I'd like to create a script that starts two shell processes in two different tabs of Windows Terminal. There is a parameter called "new-tab" but I can't make it work at all.

Is it possible to create a single script that opens Windows Terminal and run two console applications in two different tabs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By script, I hope you mean batch script, in which case try this:

```
wt.exe -w 1 nt PowerShell -c node "sample.js"
wt.exe -w 1 nt PowerShell -c npm test
```

To change the title of the tab use the `--title` argument.

```
wt.exe --title MyCoolTab
```

The full list of available command line arguments can be viewed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can run two services in a single command opening both in single Windows Terminal instance, each in its own tab. Thank you! It would be nice if I could rename title... Do you know if is it possible?

Comment: Updated the answer with the command to change the title.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you! :)